Hide some tabs in software
I have some software but I don't have the source code.
I downloaded from www.manager.io
It has many tabs when you open it.
Is there any way to hide some tabs and windows of this software?
The Tabs
I researched Software Engineering Tools and I came across the:
CFF Explorer
https://ntcore.com/explorer-suite/
But I didn't know how to use it.
Is there any good tool that can do this?
Thank you
